# Custom Controller Extension - Attempt to de-reference a null object An unexpected error has occurred

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller-extension, custom-controller

Trying to add a custom controller to a visualforce page and send through calculated values from that controller to the page to avoid lengthy formulas or conditional statements on the VF page.

```
public class VolunteerReadinessController {
    private final Contact c;   
    
    public VolunteerReadinessController (ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        this.c= (Contact)stdController.getRecord();
    }
    
    public string pipelineStage = c.Volunteer_Pipeline_Stage__c;
    
    public integer stageValue = integer.valueOf(pipelineStage.substring(0,1));
    
    public string red = '#f02e23';
    public string green = '#177021';
    
    public string lvlOne = c.Ready_L1__c == true ? green : red;
    public string lvlTwo = c.Ready_L2__c == true ? green : red;
    public string lvlThree = c.Ready_L3__c == true ? green : red;
    public string lvlThreePlus = c.Ready_L3_plus__c == true ? green : red;
    
    public string foundationTraining = c.Basic_Training_Completed__c == 'Yes' ? green : red;
    public string ukOps = c.Domestic_Operator__c == 'Yes' ? green : red;
    public string intOps = c.International_Operator__c == 'Yes' ? green : red;    
    public string heat = c.Ready_HEAT__c == true ? green : red;
    
    public string basicDBS = c.Ready_Basic_DBS__c == true ? green : red;
    public string enhancedDBS = c.Ready_Enhance_DBS__c == true ? green : red;
    public string nok = c.Ready_NOK__c == true ? green : red;
    public string passport = c.Ready_Passport__c == true ? green : red;
    public string occHealth = c.Ready_Occ_Health__c == true ? green : red;
    
    public integer columnsCourses = stageValue - 3;
    public integer columnsOther = stageValue >=6 ? 4 : 3;
    
    public string getPipelineStage() {
        return pipelineStage;
    }
    
    public integer getStageValue() {
        return stageValue;
    }
    
    public integer getColumnsCourses() {
        return columnsCourses;
    }
    
    public integer getColumnsOther() {
        return columnsOther;
    }
    
    public string getEnhancedDBS() {
        return enhancedDBS;
    }
    
    public string getBasicDBS() {
        return basicDBS;
    }
    
    public string getNok() {
        return nok;
    }
    
    public string getPassport() {
        return passport;
    }
    
    public string getOccHealth() {
        return occHealth;
    }
    
    public string getFoundationTraining() {
       return foundationTraining; 
    }
    
    public string getUkOps() {
        return ukOps;
    }
    
    public string getIntOps() {
        return intOps;
    }
    
    public string getHeat() {
        return heat;
    }
}
```

So essentially depending on the value of certain fields on the Contact record I want to colour certain boxes on the VF Page.

Error flashes up on line 8:

```
public string pipelineStage = c.Volunteer_Pipeline_Stage__c;
```

I presume it is still a null value at this point, but I am struggling to understand what I've not done, or done wrong.

*This is my first foray into Apex Classes.

Comment: I'm curious why you are using `Visualforce`. It's not really a technology worth learning any more for the most part. Are you doing this development for an email template?

Comment: We have an old banner showing very simple boxes at the top of the page which I was editing to do something more "powerful". Is there a better technology for adding this sort of visual view at the top of a Contact record you would recommend?

Comment: If you are learning the technology anyway, you should do UI work in `Lightning Web Components`.

Comment: Yes I've heard of them but haven't looked into them properly. Thanks for the top tip. Will investigate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An initializer runs before a constructor. Given this code:

```
public class Example {
  public Example(Integer value) {
    System.debug(this.value);
    this.value = value;
  }
  Integer value = 42;
}
```

The output from the debug statement will be 42, rather than null, even though the constructor comes before the initializer.

You can eliminate all the getter methods by using inline default getters and setters:

```
public class VolunteerReadinessController {
  final Contact c;

  public VolunteerReadinessController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
    this.c = (Contact) stdController.getRecord();
    string red = '#f02e23';
    string green = '#177021';
    pipelineStage = c.Volunteer_Pipeline_Stage__c;
    stageValue = integer.valueOf(pipelineStage.substring(0, 1));
    lvlOne = c.Ready_L1__c == true ? green : red;
    lvlTwo = c.Ready_L2__c == true ? green : red;
    lvlThree = c.Ready_L3__c == true ? green : red;
    lvlThreePlus = c.Ready_L3_plus__c == true ? green : red;
    foundationTraining = c.Basic_Training_Completed__c == 'Yes' ? green : red;
    ukOps = c.Domestic_Operator__c == 'Yes' ? green : red;
    intOps = c.International_Operator__c == 'Yes' ? green : red;
    heat = c.Ready_HEAT__c == true ? green : red;
    basicDBS = c.Ready_Basic_DBS__c == true ? green : red;
    enhancedDBS = c.Ready_Enhance_DBS__c == true ? green : red;
    nok = c.Ready_NOK__c == true ? green : red;
    passport = c.Ready_Passport__c == true ? green : red;
    occHealth = c.Ready_Occ_Health__c == true ? green : red;
    columnsCourses = stageValue - 3;
    columnsOther = stageValue >= 6 ? 4 : 3;
  }

  public string pipelineStage { get; set; }
  public integer stageValue { get; set; }
  public string lvlOne { get; set; }
  public string lvlTwo { get; set; }
  public string lvlThree { get; set; }
  public string lvlThreePlus { get; set; }
  public string foundationTraining { get; set; }
  public string ukOps { get; set; }
  public string intOps { get; set; }
  public string heat { get; set; }
  public string basicDBS { get; set; }
  public string enhancedDBS { get; set; }
  public string nok { get; set; }
  public string passport { get; set; }
  public string occHealth { get; set; }
  public integer columnsCourses { get; set; }
  public integer columnsOther { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this - I did realise about the { get; set; } but had already done it the long messy way and hadn't tidied up yet. Thanks for the reminder to tidy up!

Comment: @TimSomerfield Yeah, the main part of the answer was simply to say that initializers run before constructors. If you're using VS Code, you'll find it easy to clean up this kind of mess with the multi-cursor function; the entire cleanup only took like a minute or so.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of populating `pipelineStage` inline, populate it in the constructor. That way, `c` will not be null.

For example:

```
public VolunteerReadinessController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
    this.c = (Contact)stdController.getRecord();
    this.pipelineStage = this.c.Volunteer_Pipeline_Stage__c;
}

public String pipelineStage;
```

You'll need to do this with all your class level variables, as they all use `c` in some way.

Comment: And that applies to _all_ the fields, not just one.

Comment: Or to reframe it, maybe that logic just belongs in the markup and all the controller should do is set `c` after all.

Comment: This is great, I knew I'd done something dumb, thank you!

Comment: Error I'm getting now is

14:33:44:080 FATAL_ERROR System.SObjectException: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Contact.Volunteer_Pipeline_Stage__c

Is my initial query to find the contact setup wrong and only including certain fields and not the whole record?

Comment: Only fields referenced in the Visualforce page will be available. You can get around this by including other fields in a hidden section of the page. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_ApexPages_StandardController_getRecord.htm